# "object reference not set to an instance of an object error"

Tags: android, flutter, api

When I call an Api in flutter, body shows a message as follows: **"object reference not set to an instance of an object"**. But when I check it in fiddler, it shows the data. Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Object Reference related errors are run time errors not compiler errors. These errors normally come when you try to refer to a data item/variable which is null (Null Reference exception)  or else if you are trying to refer to a variable which is not yet initialized